# Android - Live audio streaming from server

Tags: android, audio, icecast, internet-radio

I have a live audio stream hosted on ice cast server. There is an API that returns the information about the audio played and also details of the actual audio being played (mp3 file).

I would like to know how to play an live audio stream from server in android app? I believe I will have to use Ice cast client? Are there any other alternative streaming APIs that I can use?

If you can point out some libraries it would be great help.

Answer (score 2):

The built in multimedia capabilities of Android should work just fine. Just give it the stream URL (**not** the playlist).

Comment: are you talking about using android multimedia player?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mediaplayer yes